# Parallel.For and Break() misunderstanding?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm investigating the Parallelism Break in a For loop.

After reading [this](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/ParallelClass.html)  and [this](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-3-imperative-data-parallelism-early-termination/)  I still have  a question:

I'd expect this code :

```
 Parallel.For(0, 10, (i,state) =>  
     { 
                Console.WriteLine(i); if (i == 5) state.Break(); 
     }
```

To yield  at *most* 6 numbers (0..6).
not only he is not doing it but have different result length :

```
02351486
013542
0135642
```

Very annoying.  (where the hell is Break() {after 5} here ??)

So I looked at msdn

> Break may be used to communicate to the loop that no other iterations after the current iteration need be run.
>   If Break is called from the 100th iteration of a for loop iterating in
>   parallel from 0 to 1000, all iterations less than 100 should still be
>   run, but the iterations from 101 through to 1000 are not necessary.

<kbd>Quesion #1 :</kbd>

Which iterations ? the overall iteration counter ? or per thread ? I'm pretty sure it is per thread. please approve.

<kbd>Question #2 :</kbd>

Lets assume we are using Parallel  +  range partition (due to no cpu cost change between elements)  so  it divides the data among threads . So if we have 4 cores (and perfect divisions among them):

```
core #1 got 0..250
core #2 got 251..500
core #3 got 501..750
core #4 got 751..1000
```

so the thread in `core #1` will meet `value=100` sometime and will break.
this will be his iteration number  `100` .
But the thread in `core #4` got more quanta and he is on `900` now. he is *way beyond* his `100'th` iteration.
He doesnt have index less 100  to be stopped !! - **so he will show them all.**

Am I right ? is that is the reason why I get more than 5 elements in my example ?

<kbd>Question #3 :</kbd>

How cn I truly break when `(i == 5)` ?

p.s.

*I mean , come on ! when I do `Break()` , I want things the loop to stop.
excactly as I do in regular `For` loop.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> To yield at most 6 numbers (0..6).

The problem is that this won't *yield at most 6 numbers*.

What happens is, when you hit a loop with an index of 5, you send the "break" request.  `Break()` will cause the loop to no longer process any values `>5`, but process all values `<5`.

However, any values greater than 5 which were already started will still get processed.  Since the various indices are running in parallel, they're no longer ordered, so you get various runs where some values `>5` (such as 8 in your example) are still being executed.

> Which iterations ? the overall iteration counter ? or per thread ? I'm pretty sure it is per thread. please approve.

This is the index being passed into Parallel.For.  Break() won't *prevent* items from being processed, but provides a guarantee that all items up to 100 get processed, but items above 100 may or may not get processed.

> Am I right ? is that is the reason why I get more than 5 elements in my example ?

Yes.  If you use a partitioner like you've shown, as soon as you call `Break()`, items beyond the one where you break will no longer get scheduled.  However, items (which is the *entire partition*) already scheduled will get processed fully.  In your example, this means you're likely to always process all 1000 items.

> How can I truly break when (i == 5) ?

You are - but when you run in Parallel, things change.  What is the *actual goal* here?  If you only want to process the first 6 items (0-5), you should restrict the items *before* you loop through them via a LINQ query or similar.  You can then process the 6 items in `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` without a `Break()` and without worry.

> I mean , come on ! when I do Break() , I want things the loop to stop. excactly as I do in regular For loop.

You should use [`Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop.aspx) instead of `Break()` if you want things to stop as quickly as possible.  This will not prevent items *already running* from stopping, but will no longer schedule any items (including ones at lower indices or earlier in the enumeration than your current position).

Comment: you mean _Break() will cause the loop to no longer process any values which their INDEX  >5_ ....right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, sort of.  Items will still be processed if they've already been scheduled and started, but no new items will get processed.  If you're in `Parallel.ForEach`, items past the location in the enumeration where you call Break() will no longer get scheduled.

Comment: @RoyiNamir No.  It's the same behavior, though `For` is "index based" and `ForEach` will be based on the original position within the enumeration.  It's effectively the same, though.

Comment: so he is wrong. http://books.google.co.il/books?id=t1de8nSVYnkC&pg=PA935&lpg=PA935&dq=%22calling+Break+yields+at+least+the+same+elements+as+executing+the+loop+sequentially:+this+example+will+always+output+at+least+the+letters%22&source=bl&ots=24qmXpHh3C&sig=Av1xFPNx7gyr6rcjB8rco8ov38k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FPVyUNiwD43ItAaLp4GABA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22calling%20Break%20yields%20at%20least%20the%20same%20elements%20as%20executing%20the%20loop%20sequentially%3A%20this%20example%20will%20always%20output%20at%20least%20the%20letters%22&f=false it wont always produce h,e,l,l,o (nevermind order)

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, he's correct.  His wording isn't super clear, though.  If you call `Break()` on the comma, the items before that `"Hello"` will all get processed, but you *might also get some items after the comma*.  He's saying "you're guaranteed to get all items before the Break() call", which is true, but he's omitting that you "may also get items after the break() call which were already being processed at the point where you Break()"

Comment: so it is basically like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/scfa9.jpg ?  and if so - what about the situation where there are only 2 threads where thread#1 got `[h,e,l,l,o]` and thread#2 got `[',',w,o,r,l,d]` ? thread 2 sends break when the index is 1. i will never see [ello] from thread #1... what am i missing ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17712/discussion-between-reed-copsey-and-royi-namir)

Comment: can you please have a look at my question here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438955/parallel-and-work-division-in-c

Answer (score 6):

> If Break is called from the 100th iteration of a for loop iterating in parallel from 0 to 1000

The 100th iteration of the loop is not necessarily (in fact probably not) the one with the index 99.

Your threads can and will run in an indeterminent order.  When the .Break() instruction is encountered, no further loop iterations will be started.  Exactly when that happens depends on the specifics of thread scheduling for a particular run.

I strongly recommend reading

[Patterns of Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)

(free PDF from Microsoft)

to understand the design decisions and design tradeoffs that went into the TPL.

Answer (score 4):

> Which iterations ? the overall iteration counter ? or per thread ?

Off all the iterations scheduled (or yet to be scheduled).

Remember the delegate may be run out of order, there is no guarantee that iteration `i == 5` will be the sixth to execute, rather this is unlikely to be the case except in rare cases.

> Q2: Am I right ?

No, the scheduling is not so simplistic. Rather all the tasks are queued up and then the queue is processed. But the threads each use their own queue until it is empty when they steal from other the threads. This leads no way to predict which thread will process what delegate.

If the delegates are sufficiently trivial it might all be processed on the original calling thread (no other thread gets a chance to steal work).

> Q3: How cn I truly break when (i == 5) ?

Don't use concurrently if you want linear (in specific) processing.

The `Break` method is there to support speculative execution: try various ways and stop as soon as any one completes.

Comment: *Don't use concurrently if you want linear (in specific) processing.*... true, but... one can ensure that a section of work happens in parallel, work is synchronized at a required point, then additional work is done in parallel until another required sync point, etc.  Just want to stress that your correct statement leaves room for that type of pattern.

Comment: @EricJ. True, but there is no evidence in the question that this is a point of synchronisation between two other pieces of work (and `Parallel.For` would often be the wrong start point for that). Rather tha Q is about a significant lack of understanding that `Parallel.For` is not a "for loop with extra magic".