# Parallel.For Properties

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int k = 0;
            int i = 3;
            var loopRes = Parallel.For (0, 20, (J) =>
            {
                k = i / J;
                Console.WriteLine ("Result After division " + J + " = " + k);
            }
            );

            if (loopRes.IsCompleted) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Loop was successful");
            }
            if (loopRes.LowestBreakIteration.HasValue) {
                Console.WriteLine ("loopRes.LowestBreakIteration.Value = " + loopRes.LowestBreakIteration.Value);
            }
        }
```

As of i read on the internet i can find 2 properties for Parallel.For & Parallel.Foreach

1. IsCompleted
2. LowestBreakIteration

For me first property is working fine. but when it comes to the situation where 3/0 then it will give the divided by zero error. so the second if loop should give me the number of LowestBreakIteration but it is throwing an error. please let me know if any body has come accross the same problem and solved it!!.

Also please explain what is the main purpose of those two properties. On what situations it wil be helpful.

Hope to hear from some one soon.

Comment: http://books.google.co.il/books?id=EvXX03I5iLYC&pg=PA936&lpg=PA936&dq=%22The+Parallel.For+and+Parallel.ForEach+methods+return%22&source=bl&ots=jFfm4zvSAZ&sig=tUY6Ht6mHYVa71BMDMNncIU-KJg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mLF2UOT4IKOx0AXIiIGADQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Parallel.For%20and%20Parallel.ForEach%20methods%20return%22&f=false

Comment: please read one of my latest questions .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784530/parallel-for-and-break-misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's throwing an exception, change your loop just a tad:

```
public static void Main (string[] args) 
{ 
    int k = 0; 
    int i = 3; 
    var loopRes = Parallel.For (0, 20, (J, loopState) => 
    { 
        try { k = i / J; }
        catch { loopState.Break(); }
        Console.WriteLine ("Result After division " + J + " = " + k); 
    } 
    ); 

    if (loopRes.IsCompleted) { 
        Console.WriteLine ("Loop was successful"); 
    } 
    if (loopRes.LowestBreakIteration.HasValue) { 
        Console.WriteLine ("loopRes.LowestBreakIteration.Value = " + loopRes.LowestBreakIteration.Value); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: calling break will cause other items not to be scheduled ( in chunk mode / range mode) which I dont think the OP will like . in range - it will continue to chunk completition - or in chunked windows size>1

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I think I'm about to learn something here, I don't follow. Do you have a link explaining that a bit further?

Comment: ofcourse.  please read one of my latest questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784530/parallel-for-and-break-misunderstanding

Comment: Thanks man , Please read also the chat between me and him. there is a link there IMHO. ( i still had somequestions to him )

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes it works and can you please provide some detailed documents link other than MSDN so that i can go through it; I have to write one report on that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see how the maximum iteration number is affected by calls to the Break method by viewing the LowestBreakIteration property of the ParallelLoopState object, as shown below:

```
Parallel.For(1, 20, (i, pls) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
        "i={0} LowestBreakIteration={1}", i, pls.LowestBreakIteration));
    if (i >= 15)
    {
        pls.Break();
    }
});

/* OUTPUT

i=10 LowestBreakIteration=
i=11 LowestBreakIteration=
i=19 LowestBreakIteration=
i=1 LowestBreakIteration=
i=2 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=3 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=6 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=7 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=8 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=9 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=12 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=13 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=14 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=15 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=4 LowestBreakIteration=19
i=5 LowestBreakIteration=15

*/
```

Reference: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ParallelLoopBreak_2.aspx